# How do I fit a JavaFX Pane to the size of its contents?

Tags: javafx

In JavaFX, I see lots of examples of how to make a child component extend its size to fit the parent pane. But I can't see how to shrink the parent pane to fit the size of its child contents.

In the following example, I create a Stage with a Scene of size 500x500 pixels. Inside that Scene is a VBox that has one child, a single Label.

I'd like the VBox Pane to be the size of the Label, not the size of the whole Stage. (In a more complex application, I'm making the VBox a draggable Pane, so I want it to be just big enough to fit its contents).

How can I do that?

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Sample  extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #efecc2");
    vbox.setPrefSize(100, 100);
    Label label = new Label("Label");
    label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightcyan");
    vbox.getChildren().add(label);
    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 500, 300);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

As you can see in the picture below, the label (with a blue background) is small, but the VBox (with a yellow background) fills the whole window. It doesn't seem to matter that I set the preferred size of the VBox to 100,100: it still fills up the whole 500 x 300 pixel Scene.

How can I tell the VBox to be only as big as the Label that is inside of it? (Or, when I add, say, 3 things inside it, to be as big as those?)
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaFX - Bind stage size to the root node's preferred size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37472448/javafx-bind-stage-size-to-the-root-nodes-preferred-size)

Comment: You set the scene to  500 x 300. What should fill it if not the vbox ?

Comment: The root of the scene is always the size of the scene. If you want the `VBox` to be smaller than the scene, put the `VBox` in another container, and make that other container the root.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it looks like I oversimplified my example. As the answer below shows, if I put the VBox inside an AnchorPane, then it works as I was hoping, i.e., the VBox fits itself to the size needed by its children.

Comment: As it turns out, my problem was because I was wrapping my VBox inside a StackPane, which apparently tries to get its children to expand to its full size, instead of an AnchorPane, which does not.

Answer (score 2):

First problem here is a scene's root object. It will always be the same size as the scene. So you need to add the parent `Pane` as root element and then add `VBox` into it.

Second problem is a type of `Pane`. Some elements affect the size of children(`BorderPane`, `StackPane`), some not (`Pane`, `AnchorPane`). So you need to choose the right parent.

Here is a simple example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Sample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label("Label");
        label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightcyan");

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #efecc2");
        vBox.getChildren().add(label);
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();

        root.getChildren().add(vBox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This does actually work as I hoped. It turns out that if the containing pane is an AnchorPane, it works how I was hoping; but if it is a StackPane (as I was previously using in my project), then it does not.

Comment: The original docs says the following: "The stackpane will attempt to resize each child to fill its content area. If the child could not be sized to fill the stackpane (either because it was not resizable or its max size prevented it) then it will be aligned within the area using the alignment property, which defaults to Pos.CENTER." This cuts off the features that you need.